# Script awk v. sed for modifying ipsec.conf

Tags: bash, sed, awk, ipsec

I am creating a script that I can run and it will simply ask me the common location name...i.e SEC-DF1 and it will fetch the ip of that site from within script. My problem is taking that IP and replacing

```
right=IP_ADDRESS
```

with

```
right=NEW_IP_ADDRESS
```

I need this so I can call the script as I will be changing the value of right so often for testing.

I have been messing with sed until someone mentioned awk...this stuff has such horrid documentation I keep getting all types errors or weird results on the test file I am messing with.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to write a script that modifies another script.  Is this correct, or do I misunderstand?

Comment: I want to place this command into a script to be run and modify a ipsec.conf file.

Comment: What have you tried? Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11194050/edit) to show before-and-after samples, and explain what you want to achieve with more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a straight forward substitution, I would just use sed:

```
sed -e 's/^right=[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/right=192.168.1.92/' filename
```

This will match `right=` at the beginning of a line followed by an IP address and replace it with the IP of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

This command will modify your *script:*

```
NEW_IP_ADDRESS=101.102.103.104 sed -i "s/^(right=).*$/\\1$NEW_IP_ADDRESS/" script
```

Comment: This is equivalent to `sed 's/^(right=).*$/\1/' script`.  The assignment of `NEW_IP_ADDRESS` does not modify the argument passed to sed.